# Where can I get the 9 patch for the Spinner used in the Android OS in the Eclipse-Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

I am looking for a png for each state, I looked in the source code and the 9 patches provided there all dont look like spinner when used as a background for one.  Please help.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look in the density-specific drawable directories in the distribution. For instance, all the 9-patches for medium density in my 2.3 distribution are at:

```
C:\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-9\data\res\drawable-mdpi\spinner_*.9.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your platform's data\resources folder.  Mine, for example, is at:

D:\Android\SDK\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-9\data\res

Where ever you installed your Android SDK just work your way down to whatever particular platform's resource folder (underneath 'data') that you like to see the various items used by Google.

Hopefully you'll find this useful.